# Scroll body to the left to a given element position

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am building a single-page history timeline microsite, and it fits automatically to the browser width.

I am trying to do that when the window is resized, body scrolls to the last clicked element. `article`'s are always full width and height. If I don't do this, when window resizing happens, everything looks very ugly.

I am trying to do this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').scrollLeft($('article#a1377').offset().left);
});
```

Which works very nice. But the thing is doing it on the last clicked element. So I was trying to do this:

```
$("header a").click(function(event){
  var element = 'article' + $(this).prop("hash");
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').scrollLeft($(element).offset().left);
});
```

But it doesn't seems to work, and element as the correct value (article#a1377).

Comment: can you give some html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript closures!!!

Element isn't visible to `resize` callback it's local to the click handler.

Assuming that `'article' + $(this).prop("hash");` is really what you're trying to return!!!

```
var lastClicked = null;
$("header a").click(function(event){
  lastClicked = 'article' + $(this).prop("hash");
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').scrollLeft($(lastClicked).offset().left);
});
```